# why magit said ' Git is already running' when i am trying to do a commit

Tags: git, emacs, magit

i am using magit in emacs , when i try to commit a change by type C-c C-c the output console shows' Git is already running', as i checked thru Git bash , it did not generete any commit .

Answer (score 11):

This seems to be a bug in magit and it happens from time to time. Killing git in the terminal with `killall git` seems to resolve the problem. As @Daimrod noted in a comment killing the `magit-display-buffer` will have the same effect.

Comment: You can also kill the buffer which contains the process (`$` → `magit-display-process`).

Comment: so for the window enviroment , i have to close the git bash windows?

Comment: Or you can kill the `magit-display-buffer` (this would kill the underlying git process as well)